# gspread_formatting not changing cell type to percentage in google doc

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-api-python-client, gspread

I'm able to run `format_cell_range()` successfully to change a cell from normal to bold and back again, but I'm unable  to change it to percent.

```py
from gspread_formatting import format_cell_range, CellFormat, NumberFormat

worksheet = <worksheet successfully auth-d and connected>
fmt = CellFormat(numberFormat=NumberFormat(type='PERCENT', pattern="0.00%"))  # define the format as percentage
format_cell_range(worksheet, 'A1', fmt)
```

I have in the cell A1 a value of 0.1, and I want it to read 10.00%

What am I doing wrong here?

I've read the docs here:

- https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/cells
- https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/cells#cellformat
- https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/cells#NumberFormat

And I'm pretty sure I've got it set up correctly, when I make the call there's a return with no replies.

If I do:

```py
    default_format = CellFormat(textFormat={'bold': False})
    format_cell_range(worksheet, 'A1', default_format)
```

or with `textFormat={'bold': False}` I'm able to switch it between bold and not bold. So it's connected, but I must be missing something in the cell format for the percentage.

I've even tried it an entirely different way just to see if it would update, and again, `textFormat` updates but not `numberFormat`

```py
spreadsheet = client.open_by_key(spreadsheet_id)
requests = [
    {
        'repeatCell': {
            'range': {
                'sheetId': worksheet.id,
                'startRowIndex': 1,
                'endRowIndex': 3,
                'startColumnIndex': 1,  
                'endColumnIndex': 3
            },
            'cell': {
                'userEnteredFormat': {
                    'numberFormat': {
                        'type': 'PERCENT',
                        'pattern': '0.00%'
                    },
                    'textFormat': {
                        'bold': True
                    },
                },
            },
            'fields': 'userEnteredFormat.numberFormat,userEnteredFormat.textFormat'
        }
    }
]
body = {
    'requests': requests
}
spreadsheet.batch_update(body)
```

I'm super stumped

Comment: About `I have in the cell A1 a value of 0.1, and I want it to read 10.00%`, if you want to change the number format of cell "A1" to `"type": "PERCENT","pattern": "0.00%"`, I think that your 1st script works. But, you say `but I'm unable to change it to percent.`. In this case, I think that it is required to know the method for correctly replicating your current situation. Can I ask you about the detailed flow for correctly replicating your current issue? I would like to confirm it.

Answer (score 0):

The code looks correct to me, except that you have to pass the range and format as a list of tuples

`format_cell_ranges(worksheet, [("A1", fmt)])`